# Upload zip to hockeyapp with VSTS fails

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, hockeyapp

**Outline**: when uploading a generated zip file to hockeyapp, the step fails with nothing in the log.

In VSTS I have this build setup

[image: Build setup]

The build step look like this
[image: MSBuild step]

The arguments sent to msbuild is

> /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\AppxPackages\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload

It builds fine, and creates my artifacts:
[image: Artifacts produced by build step]

Nothing wrong here. It is like i want it.

But something goes wrong when I try to release the _Test folder to HokeyApp. This is how my release setup

[image: Release setup]

The zip step is doing the zip fine. Creates the zip file, but when it reaches the HokeyApp step, it fails after 10-15 seconds. Here is how I have setup the hockeyapp step:
[image: HockeyApp step]

I have tried to upload the appxupload artifact, and it allows me to do so, but I dont want that. I want the zipped _Test artifact uploaded. The hokeyapp step log gives me nothing

```
2016-11-30T21:43:07.6949753Z ##[section]Starting: Upload to HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Task         : HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Description  : Deploy your alpha and beta builds of mobile apps to HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Version      : 1.0.0

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Help         : 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:09.0241255Z c1cc894e-c665-4c94-b6d1-a0fe5164fabd exists true

2016-11-30T21:43:12.5465049Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload to HockeyApp
```

How is this possible? Shouldnt I be able to upload the .zip file to HokeyApp? I can upload the _Test zip file, if I do it through VS.

I am doing something wrong here? I have used quite some time on this, so any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Here is the whole release log , just in case

```
2016-11-30T21:42:47.5913557Z ##[section]Starting: Release

2016-11-30T21:42:47.6113574Z Current agent version: '2.109.1'

2016-11-30T21:42:48.4311090Z Downloading task: ArchiveFiles

2016-11-30T21:42:50.1468654Z Downloading task: HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:42:53.1334019Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifacts

2016-11-30T21:42:53.1454012Z ReleaseId=16, TeamProjectId=44db8ed4-94b4-4e35-8cd8-205881b9686c, ReleaseDefinitionName=Tweed

2016-11-30T21:42:53.1614017Z Release folder: C:\a\r1\a

2016-11-30T21:42:53.1754004Z Environment variables available are below.  Note that these environment variables can be referred to in the task (in the ReleaseDefinition) by replacing "_" with "." e.g. AGENT_NAME environment variable can be referenced using Agent.Name in the ReleaseDefinition: 

                [AGENT_ID] --> [1]

                [BUILD_BUILDID] --> [46]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/46]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [582f0e68-9531-4663-8559-e6a12e3f8f4c]

                [REQUESTEDFORID] --> [582f0e68-9531-4663-8559-e6a12e3f8f4c]

                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [582f0e68-9531-4663-8559-e6a12e3f8f4c]

                [AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_f43ace1e-817e-4992-b28c-756a83e50efd_release_1_16_16_1]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]

                [RELEASE_RELEASENAME] --> [Release-16]

                [AGENT_VERSION] --> [2.109.1]

                [BUILD_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/46]

                [SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE] --> [release]

                [SYSTEM_CULTURE] --> [en-US]

                [BUILD_SOURCEVERSION] --> [dc3c85c0df5e4b130fad22f4ce7dbf7471a2500f]

                [SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY] --> [C:\a\r1\a]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_DEFINITIONID] --> [4]

                [AGENT_JOBSTATUS] --> [Succeeded]

                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [Tweed]

                [RELEASE_RELEASEID] --> [16]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [TfsGit]

                [MSDEPLOY_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_f43ace1e-817e-4992-b28c-756a83e50efd_release_1_16_16_1]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Martin Slot]

                [SYSTEM_TOTALJOBSINPHASE] --> [1]

                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [...]

                [RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION] --> []

                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT] --> [Tweed]

                [RELEASE_RELEASEWEBURL] --> [...]

                [SYSTEM_JOBID] --> [...]

                [AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\a\r1\a]

                [BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [Build CI package]

                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI] --> [https://martinslot.vsrm.visualstudio.com/]

                [RELEASE_RELEASEURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/16]

                [BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] --> [...]

                [AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\LR\Mms\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\2.109.1]

                [SYSTEM_WORKFOLDER] --> [C:\a]

                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]

                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]

                [AGENT_MACHINENAME] --> [TASKAGENT5-0007]

                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [TfsGit]

                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONENVIRONMENTID] --> [1]

                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTS_BETA_STATUS] --> [InProgress]

                [AGENT_WORKFOLDER] --> [C:\a]

                [BUILD_TYPE] --> [Build]

                [SYSTEM_PARALLELEXECUTIONTYPE] --> [None]

                [SYSTEM_TIMELINEID] --> [5bd0571c-c6d6-4fb7-aeeb-8cb6c84badd6]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [Build CI package]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20161130.8]

                [AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY] --> [C:\a]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [Tweed]

                [AGENT_JOBNAME] --> [Release]

                [RELEASE_DEPLOYPHASEID] --> [16]

                [BUILD_DEFINITIONID] --> [4]

                [AGENT_NAME] --> [Hosted Agent]

                [SYSTEM_JOBPOSITIONINPHASE] --> [1]

                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID] --> [16]

                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]

                [SYSTEM_ENABLEACCESSTOKEN] --> [False]

                [SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY] --> [C:\a\r1\a]

                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENTID] --> [16]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_TYPE] --> [Build]

                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [...]

                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI] --> [https://martinslot.visualstudio.com/]

                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [...]

                [SYSTEM] --> [release]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_SOURCEVERSION] --> [dc3c85c0df5e4b130fad22f4ce7dbf7471a2500f]

                [AGENT_SERVEROMDIRECTORY] --> [C:\LR\Mms\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\2.109.1\externals\vstsom]

                [SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI] --> [https://martinslot.visualstudio.com/]

                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [Martin Slot]

                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTNAME] --> [Beta]

                [SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID] --> [f43ace1e-817e-4992-b28c-756a83e50efd]

                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/16]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_BUILDID] --> [46]

                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_BUILD_CI_PACKAGE_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]

                [RELEASE_SKIPARTIFACTSDOWNLOAD] --> [False]

                [RELEASE_ATTEMPTNUMBER] --> [1]

                [SYSTEM_PLANID] --> [fccff008-3e4a-4d57-872f-35994d5c28f9]

                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID] --> [44db8ed4-94b4-4e35-8cd8-205881b9686c]

2016-11-30T21:42:53.1754004Z Downloading artifact

2016-11-30T21:42:54.0592894Z Cleaning artifacts directory: C:\a\r1\a

2016-11-30T21:42:54.0592894Z Cleaned artifacts directory: C:\a\r1\a

2016-11-30T21:42:54.0712858Z Starting artifacts download...

2016-11-30T21:42:54.1053041Z Downloading linked artifact Build CI package of type Build...

2016-11-30T21:42:54.1053041Z Created artifact folder C:\a\r1\a\Build CI package

2016-11-30T21:42:54.1875602Z Preparing to get the list of available artifacts from build

2016-11-30T21:42:54.7212893Z Preparing to download artifact: drop

2016-11-30T21:42:54.7292887Z Artifact Type: ServerDrop

2016-11-30T21:42:55.3570619Z Caching items under 'drop' in the file container...

2016-11-30T21:42:55.5149683Z Caching complete. (157 ms)

2016-11-30T21:43:00.9780683Z 10 downloads remaining.

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2739672Z Download complete.

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2759665Z 29 placed file(s): 29 downloaded, 0 empty

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2759665Z 29 MB downloaded at 2983 KB/sec. Download time: 00:00:09.7433696. Parallel download limit: 4.

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2759665Z Downloaded linked artifact Build CI package

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2759665Z Finished artifacts download

2016-11-30T21:43:05.2809727Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts

2016-11-30T21:43:05.3604337Z ##[section]Starting: Archive files 

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4024556Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4024556Z Task         : Archive Files

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4024556Z Description  : Archive files using a variety of compression formats such as .7z, .rar, .tar.gz, and .zip.

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4024556Z Version      : 1.0.9

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4024556Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4034557Z Help         : [More Information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=809083)

2016-11-30T21:43:05.4034557Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:06.2792624Z [command]C:\a\_tasks\ArchiveFiles_d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0\1.0.9\7zip\7z.exe a -tzip C:\a\r1\a\Build CI package\drop\Tweed_1.1.1.0_Test.zip Tweed_1.1.1.0_Test

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Scanning the drive:

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 20 folders, 28 files, 22367999 bytes (22 MiB)

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Creating archive: C:\a\r1\a\Build CI package\drop\Tweed_1.1.1.0_Test.zip

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Items to compress: 48

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Files read from disk: 28

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Archive size: 21992428 bytes (21 MiB)

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6809768Z Everything is Ok

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6939754Z ##[section]Finishing: Archive files 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6949753Z ##[section]Starting: Upload to HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Task         : HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Description  : Deploy your alpha and beta builds of mobile apps to HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Version      : 1.0.0

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z Help         : 

2016-11-30T21:43:07.6969757Z ==============================================================================

2016-11-30T21:43:09.0241255Z c1cc894e-c665-4c94-b6d1-a0fe5164fabd exists true

2016-11-30T21:43:12.5465049Z ##[section]Finishing: Upload to HockeyApp

2016-11-30T21:43:12.5475064Z ##[section]Finishing: Release
```

Even if i specify the zip file directly, not using the *.zip, in the hockeyapp step, it gives me the same result.

What really annoys me is the that HockeyApp task step log shows me NOTHING :) Maybe I am building it wrong? Or? Am I doing something that is not possible yet with the hockeyapp task?

I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The problem was the zip task. This task created a zip file with a the folder inside, instead of just taking all the files from the source and put in the zip. I installed "zip directories" from the market place, and it did the job.